# How to find out who is registring for lttng tracepoint probes?

Tags: lttng, babeltrace

I am getting an error as follows on running my application :

> LTTng-UST: Error (-17) while registering tracepoint probe. Duplicate
>   registration of tracepoint probes having the same name is not allowed.

Based on error, looks like multiple components are trying to register with same tracepoint probes. I am trying to find which are those components. Is there any way to see who all are registering tracepoint probes?

Thanks,
Kailas

Comment: What version of LTTng-UST and LTTng-Tools are you using? Are you using dlopen() in this application? Can you provide a reproducer of this issue (Makefile, tracepoint description and code)?This error means that one than one tracepoint probe (with identical names) are loaded in the same process.

Comment: Yes, I am using dlopen in this application

Comment: Can you provide a reproducer of this issue (Makefile, tracepoint description and code)?